# How set visibility widget in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have google maps and cluster data, when i click to some cluster then is showing  horizontal recyclerview. I have imageButton which is next or previous button in CardView, when i click it then cardView are scroll to next position. It works perfect, but i have one problem. My first cardView and the last CardView should'nt have this image button so I try set Visibility to Gone like this:

```
private void nextImageButtonAction(final ViewHolder holder, final int position, MyClusterMarkerMapItem cluster){
                if(position == clusterDataList.size()-1){
                    Log.i("position", "position: " + position + " visibility GONE for next");
                    holder.nextImageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else {
                    holder.nextImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            int currentPosition = position;
                            currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
                           // Log.i("pos", "currpos " + position + " nextPos " + currentPosition);
                            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(currentPosition++);
                        }

                    });
                }
    }

    private void previousImageButtonAction(final ViewHolder holder, final int position, MyClusterMarkerMapItem cluster) {
        if (position == 0) {
            Log.i("position", "position: " + position + " visibility GONE for prev");
            holder.previousImageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.previousImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int currentPosition = position;
                    currentPosition = currentPosition - 1;
                    //Log.i("pos", "currpos " + position + " nextPos " + currentPosition);
                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(currentPosition++);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I run this method in :

```
  public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {..My Method}
```

But the imageButton disappear in first cardView but also in the cardView which isn't first or last, and the last cardview doesn't have prev and next image button but should have prev image button. 
So how can I have next and prev image button in all cardView instead in first should have only next and the last should have only prev

My Adapter and more:

```
    public class ClusterInfoWindow extends Fragment {
    private MyClusterMarkerMapItem clusterData;
    private List<MyClusterMarkerMapItem> clusterDataList;
    public void setClusterData(MyClusterMarkerMapItem clusterData) {
        clusterDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.clusterData = clusterData;
    }
    public void setClusterDataList(List<MyClusterMarkerMapItem> clusterDataList) {
        this.clusterDataList = new ArrayList<>(clusterDataList);
    }
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapterRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    private  View rootView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info_window_marker_map, container, false);
        setUpCardView(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }
    private void setUpCardView(View rootView){
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewInfoWindowMarker);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(rootView.getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false); //horizontal
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapterRecyclerView = new AdapterRecyclerView(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRecyclerView);
    }

    class AdapterRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
        private Context context;
        public AdapterRecyclerView(Context context){
            this.context = context;
        }
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_for_info_window_map,parent,false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
//some function, some i put above in this post
}
 @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            int itemCount = 0;
            if (clusterDataList.size() == 0)
                itemCount = 1;
            else if(clusterDataList.size() > 0 )
                itemCount = clusterDataList.size();
            return itemCount;
        }
        public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            private ImageButton nextImageButton;
            private ImageButton previousImageButton;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                nextImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewNext);
                previousImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardVievPrevious);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `holder.nextImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` into `else` statement

**WHY?**:
Because RecyclerView is reusing views. Once the view is out of the screen from top, it is moved to the bottom to represent the next list item. And since you have hidden the button in it, it won't automatically show it, you need to do that manually.